# W3C geolocation backend implementations and extensions

Tags: browser, geolocation, wifi, w3c-geolocation

Could someone provide a link to a description of backend implementation(s) of the Geolocation APIs available in modern browsers?

Specifically, I need to make sure that a bunch of WiFi spots are registered (and preferably promptly updated on their positions changes) on the server-side of the Geolocation APIs and get used for a user location detection. Can this be done by some requests to some authority or performed automatically according to a specific algorithm? If the latter, than what is the algorithm, and what are the options for interactions?